# Blocked transactions in ABAP-based SAP software

Tags: sap-basis

What table and what field store the property for blocked transactions?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Try to work it into a little bit better sentence.

Comment: If you mean which field on which table shows if a transaction is locked or unlocked then your answer is TSTC-CINFO. And please rephrase your question.

Comment: SE11 or SE16 to browse the table contents. Make sure you enter "20" TO "24" as the "HEX01 VALUE. This will list all the transactions locked in the system.

Comment: You really don't make any sense. Did you ask which table/field shows locked transactions? It seems you are answering to a  different question which paradoxically you asked.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned early, transaction lock is specified by the TSTC-CINFO field. This field is 1 byte flag set. Code below demonstarates technique of flags decoding:

```
TABLES: tstc.  
DATA: x01 TYPE x VALUE '01',  
      x02 TYPE x VALUE '02',  
      x20 TYPE x VALUE '20',  
      x80 TYPE x VALUE '80'.  
SELECT * FROM tstc.  

  IF tstc-cinfo O x80.  
    " Report transaction  
  ENDIF.  

  IF tstc-cinfo O x01.  
    " Menu transaction.  
  ENDIF.  

  IF tstc-cinfo O x02.  
    " Parameter transaction  
  ENDIF.  

  IF tstc-cinfo O x20.  
    " Locked.  
    NEW-LINE.  
    WRITE: 'Locked:', tstc-tcode.  
  ENDIF.  

ENDSELECT.
```